# Get all sessions from memcached with Django

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework, memcached

I'm using memcached to store my session. Is there a way to get all the session from memcached displayed? I'm looking for a way to manage the sessions and delete the sessions manually through some user interface

Comment: Have you tried using Admin Panel for that?

Comment: I have, by default nothing exposes the session itself to the Django admin panel. The idea is to query the memcached and display them in a custom made UI so I can manipulate them as the superuser